# React - How to move element based on scrolling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

What I'm looking to do is pretty simple in Javascript/jQuery, but when you throw React in the mix, it's baffling me as I'm trying to do things the "React" way. So the scenario is I have a div about 300px tall, with Element A inside. What I'm trying to do is this:

- Detect scrolling on the whole document
- When scrollTop gets to parent's position, start moving Element A downward
- When scrollTop is past Element A's parent bottom, stop moving the element
- Then vice versa when scrolling up

I have tried doing a normal `position: relative` on the parent, then `position: absolute` on Element A, then using the scroll event in `componentDidMount` to do calculations, but things became choppy and it didn't feel quite right.

Has anyone done this in React?

Comment: Why not use an existing component that give you this functionality? react-sticky for example

Comment: I feel silly. I ran across that but never looked at the demo because I thought it was for fixed elements in relation to the document. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Dekel's comment above, the (quick) answer is to use `react-sticky` which can be found in NPM's registry.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky